# Use Mage::app('admin') in Composer post scripts

Tags: magento-1.9, composer

I am creating a post-update-cmd script in which I call some functions.

The file is

> lib\Vendor\Module\CustomClass.php

This is the command:

```
"post-update-cmd": [
Vendor \\ Module \\ CustomClass :: customfunc
]
```

and the file:

```
namespace Vendor\Module;

class CustomClass  {

// .. some stuff for get rootfolder (in this case is /../../../../../../

public static function customfunc() {
  if(file_exists(self::$MagentoRootFolder.'/app/Mage.php') == true){
      $bootstrapFileName = self::$MagentoRootFolder.'/app/Mage.php';
  }
 else{
      die("Mage.php file not found in ./app or parent folder");
  }

try{
      require self::$MagentoRootFolder . '/app/bootstrap.php';
      require_once $bootstrapFileName;
      umask(0);

    }
    catch (\Exception $e){
      die($e->getMessage());
    }


    Mage::app('admin');

}
```

But when i run composer update the result is this:

> [ErrorException] include (Vendor \ Module \ Mage.php): failed to open
>   stream: No such file or directory

How can I **include** `Mage: app` to work also **within this path**?